# ANOVA shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, anova

I am trying to get this ANOVA Shiny app to run with no luck. The output should be a list so maybe I am confused on how to output those data  types. Any suggestions?

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(car)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  csvfile <- reactive({

    csvfile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(csvfile)){return(NULL)}
    dt <- read.csv(csvfile$datapath, header=input$header, sep=input$sep)
    dt

  })

  output$var <- renderUI({

     if(is.null(input$file1$datapath)){return()}

     else list (

       radioButtons("dvar", "Please Pick The Dependent Variable", choices =    names(csvfile())),
       radioButtons("ivar", "Please Pick The Independent Variable", choices = names(csvfile())),
      actionButton("submit", "Submit")

     )
  })

  output$aovSummary = renderTable({
    if (is.null(input$file1$datapath)){return()}

    if (input$submit > 0) {

      if (input$type == 'type1'){

        isolate(anova(lm(csvfile()[,input$dvar] ~ csvfile()[,input$ivar], data = csvfile()))

  }

  if (input$type == 'type2'){

    isolate(Anova(lm(csvfile()[,input$dvar] ~ csvfile()[,input$ivar], data = csvfile()), Type = "II", test.statistic = "F"))

      }

      if (input$type == 'type3'){

        isolate({
          fit <- aov(csvfile()[,input$dvar] ~ csvfile()[,input$ivar], data = csvfile()))
          drop1(fit, ~ . , test = 'F')
        })

      }

    }})

})
```

ui.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  headerPanel('Analysis of Variance'),

  sidebarPanel(

    fileInput("file1", "CSV File", accept=c("text/csv", "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain", ".csv")),

    checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),

    radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
             c(Comma=',',
               Semicolon=';',
               Tab='\t'),
             ','),

    selectInput('type', 'Please select Sums of Squares type', 
            c(I = 'type1', II = 'type2', III = 'type3'), 'type1'),

    uiOutput('var')

  ),

  mainPanel(

    h3('ANOVA Table'),
    verbatimTextOutput('aovSummary')

  )
))
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What exactly is not working? Do you see the controls?

Comment: @John Paul There is no output, it seems to be returning a null response and I am not sure why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried to run your code. There were formatting issues. The code below runs for me. I have no csv to test it with but it may work for you.

```
library(shiny)
library(car)

runApp(
  list(
    ui = pageWithSidebar(
      headerPanel('Analysis of Variance'),
      sidebarPanel(
        fileInput("file1", "CSV File", accept=c("text/csv", "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain", ".csv")),
        checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
        radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',c(Comma=',',Semicolon=';',Tab='\t'),','),
        selectInput('type', 'Please select Sums of Squares type', 
                    c(I = 'type1', II = 'type2', III = 'type3'), 'type1')
        ,uiOutput('var') 
      )
      , mainPanel(    
        h3('ANOVA Table'),
        tableOutput('aovSummary')
      )
    )
    , server = function(input, output, session) {
      csvfile <- reactive({
        csvfile <- input$file1
        if (is.null(csvfile)){return(NULL)}
        dt <- read.csv(csvfile$datapath, header=input$header, sep=input$sep)
        dt
      })
      output$var <- renderUI({
        if(is.null(input$file1$datapath)){
          return()
        }else{
          list (radioButtons("dvar", "Please Pick The Dependent Variable", choices =    names(csvfile())),
                radioButtons("ivar", "Please Pick The Independent Variable", choices = names(csvfile())),
                actionButton("submit", "Submit")
          )
        }
      })

      output$aovSummary = renderTable({
        if(is.null(input$file1$datapath)){return()}
        if(input$submit > 0){
          if(input$type == 'type1'){
            return(isolate(anova(lm(csvfile()[,input$dvar] ~ csvfile()[,input$ivar], data = csvfile()))))
          }
          if(input$type == 'type2'){
            return(isolate(Anova(lm(csvfile()[,input$dvar] ~ csvfile()[,input$ivar], data = csvfile())), Type = "II", test.statistic = "F"))
          }
          if(input$type == 'type3'){
            isolate(
              fit <- aov(csvfile()[,input$dvar] ~ csvfile()[,input$ivar], data = csvfile())
            )
            return(drop1(fit, ~ . , test = 'F'))
          }
        }
      })
    })
)
```

Comment: It still does not produce an output. I'm an idiot and entered unformatted code, sorry about that. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Do you have a csv to test it with?

Comment: You were right, just in ui the verbatimTextOutput command needs to be tableOutput. So I will give it to you. Thank you.

Comment: Oh and return wrappers around the Anova() functions tests